# insertig arabic text with in ODBC PHP Driver with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, character-encoding, odbc, arabic-support

In our application, we are using Ms Sql database and it is hosted on sqladmin.winhost.com. We have PHP install with ODBC driver along with Windows server. The database is Using the Collation "**Arabic_CI_AI**".

Below is the code for simple inserting data to a Table. The query is executed success fully but arabic data lost and insted some random string is table.

When the Value of $request['username'] is "احمد علي عريبي" in dtabase it is received with some random string.

```
<?php 

$connectionString = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' . SERVER_NAME . ';DATABASE=' . DB_NAME;
$conn = odbc_connect($connectionString, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
  $request=$_POST;      
echo $sql="INSERT INTO MobileNotificaiton.emp_user VALUES('test@gmail.com','MXI',200,'{$request['username']}','123','12365897452',1,'','','','')";        

        $results = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

    $close = odbc_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Can any one guid me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the encoding of the (arabic) data inside your php application? UTF-8? What is the column type of the corresponding column in SQL Server? Nvarchar?

Comment: In PHP application Arabic encoding is UTF-8, Column type is nvarchar and collation of Database is Arabic_CI_AI

Comment: Have you tried `N'{$request['username']}'`.  Placing the `N` before a string will ensure that the unicode value is used. See info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/239530/you-must-precede-all-unicode-strings-with-a-prefix-n-when-you-deal-with-unicode-string-constants-in-sql-server)

Comment: @chrisuae: But then he will try to store utf-8 encoded data into a nvarchar column that expects utf-16 - not? IMHO he would first need to convert utf-8 to utf-16, and then insert using 'N'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution.
I converted the Arabic text to binary in PHP and then while inserting data to MSSQL using CAST function of MSSQL convert this binary data to its desired data type.

```
$connectionString = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' . SERVER_NAME . ';DATABASE=' . DB_NAME;
$conn = odbc_connect($connectionString, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
$request=$_POST;      
$data = iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2LE", $request['username']);
$unpacked = unpack('H*hex', $data);
$username='0x' . strtoupper($unpacked['hex']);

$sql="INSERT INTO MobileNotificaiton.emp_user VALUES('test@gmail.com','MXI',200,'{$username}','123','12365897452',1,'','','','')";        
$results = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
$close = odbc_close($conn);
```

While fetching the data from the database we use the same process in reverse order. This way data is compatible in .NET application and in PHP application. That is what my requirement was.